# What would be the best solution to manage automation via multiple browsers hosted on dedicated server?

Tags: node.js, automation, puppeteer

I'm using Puppeeter for NodeJS to automate tasks in Chrome, and there're about 15-20 browsers running concurrently on Windows Server. What would be the most efficient and "right" way to accomplish easy management of these sessions? I've thought about web app communicating with the main NodeJS app via POST/GET requests.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is tagged with playwright, I thought I'd suggest using browser contexts instead of or in addition to full browsers. Browser contexts are much more lightweight to start and destroy, and they are isolated too, and can be used in parallel.
https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-browsercontext
(I suppose Puppeteer might have these as well, but couldn't quickly find how to use them there.)

About communicating with these browsers, it's up to you. Maybe grpc is a bit more efficient for this purpose. Also something like the actor model might be worth looking at for a nice concurrency model.

And if you're looking for maximum scale, high elasticity, and not having to manage VMs yourself, the examples of running PlayWright in AWS Lambda or Azure Functions are also worth a look.
https://playwright.dev/docs/showcase#examples

Comment: grpc seems to be the solution. Thanks! 
Though unfortunately, I cannot upvote your answer.